# WMT'15 newstest dataset: .sgm formatting

Tags: xml, machine-learning, nlp, moses

What scripts are used (and how?) to get the newstest datasets from [wmt](http://www.statmt.org/wmt15/translation-task.html) from the .sgm format to an unformatted format (like the europarl dataset)?

e.g. the newstest dataset downloaded at: http://www.statmt.org/wmt15/test.tgz

contains (when extracted) files such as newstest2015-ende-ref.de.sgm

How do I make that similar to the europarl dataset where each line represents a sentence with no formatting?

Note:

I have found a script in the moses directory (linked from the wmt site) called [wrap-xml.perl](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/scripts/ems/support/wrap-xml.perl).
It mentions in the test section that it is used to go to .sgm format, but the script itself contains no documentation (and I am clueless in perl)

Comment: SGM files are a little irritating so we created this: https://github.com/alvations/warmth/blob/master/wmt_metric_task_data_indices.py#L177

Comment: BTW, the WMT test sets should not be from Europarl. Possibly, if you're looking for Europarl, this is what you're looking for http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/Europarl.php , e.g. plaintext format: http://opus.lingfil.uu.se/download.php?f=Europarl/de-en.txt.zip . Painstakingly compiled by Jorg Tiedemann =)

Comment: @alvas thanks for your response, I am looking for the wtm'15 to compare with luong/chungs results on machine translation.

I tried running the script you supplied, by outcommenting what is in the bottom and placing range(14, 15), got an error about missing the `'metric_data/WMT14/references/newstest2014-ref.hi-en'`, but this is not in the sgm format? how does this handle the .sgm format?